# Quartz plugin for Grails

Tags: grails, quartz-scheduler, grails-plugin, grails-2.5

I'm testing quartz plugin with Grails 2.5.1. Below is the Job code:

```
class TestingJob {
    static triggers = {
      simple name: 'mySimpleTrigger', startDelay: 60000, repeatInterval: 1000l, repeatCount: 10
    }

    def execute() {
      println (" Hi ")
    }
}
```

As per my understanding from the [documentation](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-quartz/guide/scheduling.html) , `Hi` is supposed to be printed 11 times, but actually, it's only printed 2 times. Am I missing something?

Comment: Try using `println (new Date())` and see what happens. You'll likely find that since the console output was duplicated beyond the second output that the console quietly filtered it out.

Comment: `test.TestingJob  Hi Tue Dec 29 01:19:22 EET 2015
test.TestingJob  Hi Tue Dec 29 01:19:23 EET 2015
test.TestingJob  Hi Tue Dec 29 01:19:24 EET 2015
test.TestingJob  Hi Tue Dec 29 01:19:25 EET 2015
test.TestingJob  Hi Tue Dec 29 01:19:26 EET 2015
test.TestingJob  Hi Tue Dec 29 01:19:27 EET 2015
test.TestingJob  Hi Tue Dec 29 01:19:28 EET 2015
test.TestingJob  Hi Tue Dec 29 01:19:29 EET 2015
test.TestingJob  Hi Tue Dec 29 01:19:30 EET 2015
test.TestingJob  Hi Tue Dec 29 01:19:31 EET 2015
test.TestingJob  Hi Tue Dec 29 01:19:32 EET 2015` this was the output, now it's working fine !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `println (new Date())` and see what happens.

You'll see that since the console output was duplicated beyond the second output that the console quietly filtered it out.

The job is actually running as expected.